# AdMob not displaying fully on some devices

Tags: android, admob, andengine, ads, 2d-games

I recently published an app on Google Play "Meteor Dodge" developed in AndEngine and I have a problem with displaying ads on some devices. It seems that the ad is showing only 5-10% of the height at the beginning but after the refresh interval it appears perfect. I can't resolve this issue please help. Here is my code:

```
@Override
protected void onSetContentView() {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    // CREATING the parent FrameLayout //
    final FrameLayout frameLayout = new FrameLayout(this);

    // CREATING the layout parameters, fill the screen //
    final FrameLayout.LayoutParams frameLayoutLayoutParams = new FrameLayout.LayoutParams(
            FrameLayout.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT,
            FrameLayout.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT);


    // CREATING a Smart Banner View //
    this.adView = new AdView(this);
    this.adView.setAdSize(com.google.android.gms.ads.AdSize.BANNER);
    this.adView.setAdUnitId("ca-app-pub-xxxxxxxxxx/xxxxxxxxxx");


    // Doing something I'm not 100% sure on, but guessing by the name //
    adView.refreshDrawableState();
    adView.setVisibility(AdView.VISIBLE);

 // Adview layout //
    final FrameLayout.LayoutParams adViewLayoutParams =
            new FrameLayout.LayoutParams(LinearLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT,
                    FrameLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT,
                                         Gravity.RIGHT|Gravity.TOP); 

    // REQUEST an ad 
    final AdRequest adRequest = new AdRequest.Builder().build();
    adView.loadAd(adRequest); 
    adView.bringToFront();

    // RENDER the add on top of the scene //
    this.mRenderSurfaceView = new RenderSurfaceView(this);
    mRenderSurfaceView.setRenderer(mEngine, this);

    // SURFACE layout ? //
    final android.widget.FrameLayout.LayoutParams surfaceViewLayoutParams =
            new FrameLayout.LayoutParams(super.createSurfaceViewLayoutParams());

    // ADD the surface view and adView to the frame //
    frameLayout.addView(this.mRenderSurfaceView, surfaceViewLayoutParams);
    frameLayout.addView(adView, adViewLayoutParams);

    // SHOW AD //
    this.setContentView(frameLayout, frameLayoutLayoutParams);


}
```

Answer (score 0):

Get rid off (they are not necessary)

```
adView.refreshDrawableState();
adView.setVisibility(AdView.VISIBLE);

adView.bringToFront();
```

Replace

```
final FrameLayout.LayoutParams adViewLayoutParams =
        new FrameLayout.LayoutParams(LinearLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT,
                FrameLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT,
                                     Gravity.RIGHT|Gravity.TOP);
```

with

```
final FrameLayout.LayoutParams adViewLayoutParams =
        new FrameLayout.LayoutParams(FrameLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT,
                FrameLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT,
                                     Gravity.RIGHT|Gravity.TOP);
```

and most importantly don't call

```
adView.loadAd(adRequest);
```

until *after*  you have added the AdView to the FrameLayout and the ContentView has been set.

Comment: I don't know why but this happens only on some devices

Comment: If it only happens on some devices then you need to include that information in your question. Also make sure you do a clean build.

Comment: I am making a clean build and I did include it in my question.